# Descriptions within Quote Environment with Only Certain Items Indented

Tags: lists, indentation, description, quoting, hangindent

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=.3in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\textheight=5.25in
\usepackage[frame,noinfo,center]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\footnotesize

\begin{quote}
\item \centering\textbf{CATEGORY}

\begin{description}
\item \textbf{Group1}

\item \lipsum[101]

\item Ecce non incisum.

\item

\item \textbf{Group2}
\end{description}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

I would like to indent the non-Group items; that is, in this case, the items containing the Latin.

I know that if I insert, say, `\hskip 7pt` after each of those items, I will get the desired indentation on the first line only---and so, the hanging indentation will be reduced by that amount---which is not what I am looking for. (Besides, if I had one hundred such items, it would be a laborious chore.)

QUESTION: How may I *a priori* specify an indentation for all non-Group items without affecting the hanging indent? Also, is there a way to specify a particular hanging indent?

*Remark*: Perhaps there is a better way to code what I would like to accomplish; if so, please advise.

Thank you.